# Discrete colorbar with postscript output in Matlab

Tags: matlab, postscript, colorbar

I have a figure created in Matlab which uses a discrete colorbar and a custom colormap. Ideally, I would like to save this as a postscript figure (.eps) so I can do some editing in Inkscape. However, when I save it in .eps format, the colorbar appears to be continuous when viewed in Inkscape (amongst other progams). What do I need to do to stop this?

I also tried saving the figure as a PDF which seemed to work (colorbar was discrete in any program I used to view/edit it), but after some editing in Inkscape and re-saving as a PDF (or other format like .eps and .png), the colorbar switched back to continuous again.

Here is the code for my colorbar and what I used to save it:

```
cmap=[118 18 19;
      118 18 19;
      184 18 21;
      230 38 44;
      255 127 0;
      255 191 0;
      247 217 9;
      255 248 140;
      182 237 240; 
      145 205 237;
      107 174 232;
      61 144 227;
      32 114 214;
      0 66 135;
      0 31 103;
      0 31 103;
      0 31 103;
      0 31 103;
      0 31 103;
      0 31 103];
cmap=cmap/255;
colormap(cmap)
caxis([-20 30]
cb=colorbar('XTick',[-15 -12.5 -10 -7.5 -5 -2.5 0 2.5 5 7.5 10 12.5 15],'Xlim', [-17.5 17.5]);
export_fig fig1 -pdf -eps -r600 -painters
```

Here is the PDF version of the colorbar (hopefully). I couldn't work out how to post the EPS version.

[image]

How do I stop the colorbar from going continuous? I really need to do some editing as I can't get Matlab to do arrows on the end of my colorbar, and I might need to play around with the text too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I managed to find to stop this is to re-colour each section of the colour bar in Inkscape with the discrete colour that was meant to be in that section. In reality, I think this just inserted another rectangle of that colour within that box, but it worked ok. This wouldn't work if my tickmarks didn't completely separate each section of the colourbar though.

Not a pretty solution, but it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue to do with how Inkscape exports bitmaps, discussed [here](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=15829). The solution is to open the offending pdf file (the one output by Inkscape) in a text editor, find the line(s)

```
/Interpolate true
```

and replace it/them with

```
/Interpolate false
```

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but how do I open a pdf file in a text editor? I am a Windows user, just in case that makes a difference.
I have tried in the various editors I have, and it doesn't show me anything understandable!

Comment: Drag the pdf file into your MATLAB editor window - it will open as a text file. Then hit ctrl+F and type `\Interpolate true` in the "Find what" box, `\Interpolate false` in the "Replace with" box, and click "Replace All". Save the file, then open it in Adobe Reader and see if the interpolation has disappeared.

Comment: Ok, I have opened the PDF in the Matlab editor window, but it still looks like random characters everywhere. There are a few lines of legible code, and the find didn't find `\Interpolate` anywhere (I tried with a lower case "i" as well. I must be doing something wrong!

Comment: Shame. All I can say is that it worked for me on your example. Perhaps the actual figure you create is more complicated.

Comment: By the way, you should do this on the pdf output by Inkscape, not the pdf output by export_fig().

Comment: Aha, this may be where I was going wrong. Will try on the inkscape PDF

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47847/discussion-between-emmalgale-and-user664303)

Comment: I realise there was a typo in my comment above, by my answer was correct. Search for `/Interpolate` instead of `\Interpolate`!

Comment: Following some more discussion, unfortunately this doesn't work for my figure (we aren't sure why), but it may well work for other people.

Answer (score 0):

You may print in vector format with

```
print(gcf, '-dpdf', 'fig.pdf');
```

You can also set the `renderer` property of the figure to `zbuffer` for a raster plot.

```
set(gcf,'Renderer','zbuffer');
```

Both display and print a discrete colorbar.

Comment: The renderer used for on-screen rendering is different from the renderer used for hardcopy output. Also, you only ever want to use the painters renderer for vector format output.

Comment: I don't want a raster plot. It needs to be a vector one.